# Multiplayer Spawning in UE4 blueprint

Tags: multiplayer, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

i want to create a local multiplayer game for 2-4 players. 
It seems like i have made a mistake or it is a bug. I tried different tutorials but i dont get my mistake. I posted the same question in the answer hub of unreal, but i didn´t get a response. Here ist my gamemode and the spawning function:
[GamemodeSpawning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l1px.png)

My Pawn is called Physics Ball BP. The default spawn in the gamemode is disabled. The default value of the variable "Max Player Amount" is 2. "Player Start Array" contains the PlayerStarts. The PlayerStarts have the tag "0" and "1". This is my viewport before the start: 
[Viewport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1PAK.png)

This is my viewport if i press Play: [ViewportPlaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snd2D.jpg)

I think i just missed something basic, but i cant figure out what i´ve done wrong. I hope you can help me.

best regards chris

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you did it on purpose but you uploaded the same screenshot of your viewport twice. Maybe edit your post, and upload the right ones.

But maybe the problem your having is because you forgot to plug your `Index` variable into the `Player Int` variable in the `Spawn Actor` node?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it should be the correct picture now.


The `Player Int` variable isn´t the problem, because i use the reference of the spawned actor for the `Possess` node.

Comment: Did you set your own gamemode with your own default player in the world settings?

Comment: Yes the gamemode is the right one. I disabled the default spawn, because i want to initiate the spawning by myself. 
In the last screenshot you can see all the actors. The amount of them are right, but somehow the Player 1 Controller is messed up.